# Is there a way to GWT compiler/serializer/linker issue?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

Lets say I have a class...

**com.mycom.app.AbstractMessage**

There is another class in

**com.mycom.model.QueryResponse**

QueryResponse extends AbstractMessage and notice they are in different pacakges

**com.mycom.model** is a GWT Module and in the module XML

When I compile model there are errors. However when I try to use QueryReponse in another GWT module, I get runtime errors

*"No source code is available for type com.mycom.app.AbstractMessage; did you forget to inherit a required module"*

This lends me to believe that AbstractMessage was not compiled/compiled right to begin understandably because I DO NOT WANT to have "app" package be a GWT module

In other words, I only want to compile all classes in "model" and not any super classes. How can I tell the GWT compiler/rpc/linker/serializer etc not to do so?

i.e Is there a way to tell GWT not to walk beyond certain classes when it serializing/compiling it

I am doing this a source environment where we have a lot of packages, most of them depend on MODEL only and I DO NOT want to make a GWT module out of every package, just so it compiles.

Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little bit of research on this one, you are right GWT will look for all implementations of an Abstract class, if and only if, the AbstractClass is referenced in an RPC GWTAsync interface, even though some are in non-GWT packages.

Let's say an object of type AbstractClass comes in over the network, and the GWT deserializer is now tasked with coverting the network data into a specific instance. It needs to know about all implementations of AbstractClass, to find which is coming over the network right now! -- So to accomplish this it, at compiletime, generates a .rpc file for each GWT service interface, listing all possible concrete types that the service methods can return.

Ray Ryan (Google employee) once mentioned that it is a bad idea to use interfaces arguments or return types in any RPC interface. - because it makes it difficult for the deserializer to know the exact type.

You can hand edit the generated RPC file and remove the offending types, or mark the other implementations as Non Serializable by not implementing Serializable in those implementations in other packages.

A Better way could be - I suspect you wrote code : "implements java.io.Serializable" at the top level (for the AbstractClass itself), maybe it's now time to move it to each implementation.

Now the GWT RPC deserializer's task is clear and straightforward - it knows that only certain implementations (that are serializable) of the AbstractClass will come over the network, and reach and compile them only. So it will not compile the other non serializable subclassess of your AbstractClass - as it knows they arent serializable.

Comment: makes sense,but I checked & nothing is marked Seriliazable. In the async interface call is `searchQuery(QueryRequest grequest, AsyncCallback<QueryResponse> callback);` and in the Remoteservice its `QueryResponse searchQuery(QueryRequest grequest)`. QueryRequest and QueryResponse extend AbstractPlatformMessage. All of these classes are in package and gwt module MODEL. Now in non gwt package there is `abstract class CgiResponse extends AbstractPlatformMessage`. This causes my issue. NONE of these classes are marked serializable. Does this give you more clues?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Moving **AbstractMessage** into the models package - as it is the model **QueryResponse**'s super class.

And also inhertance in models is only a good idea, if you have 0 fields and only methods(behaviour) in the super class.

Lastly, if  GWT is to make your **QueryResponse** into javascript - it needs ALL Types mentioned in the source file, to compile properly. So do not mention any server-only-classes in a source file meant to become javascript.

Have a region that has all the server-side java classes that will be run in a JVM on the server, and another region full of source files that will be compiled into javascript by the GWT compiler. **The server-side region code/classes CAN refer to client region code/classes but defenitely NOT the vice versa**. Make sure that no code thats gonna become javascript is referring (even an unused import statement) to a server side class.

GWT compiler works with source files only, however you need to compile client code into .class files so your serverside classes can refer to them.

NEW EDIT :

I did a little bit of research on this one, you are right GWT will look for all implementations of an Abstract class, if and only if, the AbstractClass is referenced in an RPC GWTAsync interface, even though some are in non-GWT packages.

Let's say an object of type AbstractClass comes in over the network, and the GWT deserializer is now tasked with coverting the network data into a specific instance. It needs to know about all implementations of AbstractClass, to find which is coming over the network right now! -- So to accomplish this it, at compiletime, generates a .rpc file for each GWT service interface, listing all possible concrete types that the service methods can return.

Ray Ryan (Google employee) once mentioned that it is a bad idea to use interfaces arguments or return types in any RPC interface. - because it makes it difficult for the deserializer to know the exact type.

You can hand edit the generated RPC file and remove the offending types, or mark the other implementations as Non Serializable by not implementing Serializable in those implementations in other packages.

A Better way could be -
I suspect you wrote code : "implements java.io.Serializable" at the top level (for the AbstractClass itself), maybe it's now time to move it to each implementation.

Now the GWT RPC deserializer's task is clear and straightforward - it knows that only certain implementations (that are serializable) of the AbstractClass will come over the network, and reach and compile them only. So it will not compile the other non serializable subclassess of your AbstractClass - as it knows they arent serializable.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase this as the example might not been clear. Say, the abstract class and one of its implementation are in same package model. But another class in another package also implements this abstract class. Now when I compile with GWT why does it need to go look at all implementations of that abstract class in other pacakges? What is the way to stop it.

Comment: I understand. What blocks us from letting GWT know 1) The abstract class itself and 2) One of its implementations( the QueryResponse ).

The other implementations (say NewMessage) may be elsewhere in other packages that are not even GWT modules. GWT compiler won't complain/compile other implementations exist elsewhere. It will not look into non-GWT modules.

Comment: Well it is Zasz! If i have an abstract class in one of my GWT modules and it is being implemented by a class in another non GWT package, at runtime the hosted mode complains about not finding the source of that other implementing class. that is what is baffling me.

Comment: makes sense,but I checked & nothing is marked Seriliazable. In the async interface call is   `searchQuery(QueryRequest grequest, AsyncCallback<QueryResponse> callback);` and in the Remoteservice its ` QueryResponse searchQuery(QueryRequest grequest)`. QueryRequest and QueryResponse extend AbstractPlatformMessage. All of these classes are in package and gwt module MODEL. Now in non gwt package there is `abstract class CgiResponse extends AbstractPlatformMessage`. This causes my issue. NONE of these classes are marked serializable. Does this give you more clues?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option : If as I suspect you are using the command pattern - I have seen all the abstract interfaces, super classes for Command and Response etc always go in the client side packages - i.e., those that are GWT compiled. They are referrable and usable and instantiable for the server end of the application - so these source files are compiled twice, once by GWT into javascript for browser usage, and once by javac into bytecode for allowing reference from serverside. Thus in all GWT modules, including gwt-user.jar if you open them with 7Zip or WinZip you will see source and class files JARed together.

Comment: yes the model package is client because I am 1) compiling it expressly via module xml 2. another GWT module is using its client side. The problem is not more or so to do with command pattern by GWT trying to speculatively pick up sources that i do not want it to consider in compiling.